# How come std::unique_lock offers template and MoveConstructible at the same time?

Tags: c++, c++11

I read that Move assignment operator and Copy assignment operator are non-template and non-static member function.
If this is the case how is it possible that the `std::unique_lock` able to do Move and be templated at the same time?
I can see that `std::unique` uses template heavily.
Am I missing something here?

```
std::mutex m;

std::unique_lock<std::mutex>  lock_a(m, std::defer_lock);
                   ^^^
```

Comment: The [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) ***class*** is a template class. It's member functions doesn't have to be. Not that it matters, the move constructor and move assignment operator are just normal member functions, and can be template member function like any other member function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So you mean move assignment operator can be templated?

Comment: @pokche : No, the type the necessarily _non-template_ move assignment operator belongs to can be templated. Note that you can also have templated assignment operators that move, that just don't happen to be "move assignment operator"s.

Comment: @ildjarn so some where inside unique_lock there is templated assignment operators that is making the unique_lock movable?

Comment: @pokche : There is a _non_-template move-assignment operator that allows moving from other `unique_ptr`s of _the same_ type, then also a templated assignment operator that allows moving from other `unique_ptr`s of _compatible_ type. The latter is an assignment operator that moves, but it is not _the move-assignment_ operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that Move assignment operator and Copy assignment operator are non-template and non-static member function.

They can be template member method.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct S {
    template<typename U>
    friend class S;

    S() { t = new T; }
    ~S() { delete t; }

    S& operator=(S &&o) {
        std::cout << "non-template move" << std::endl;
        std::swap(t, o.t);
        return *this;
    }

    S& operator=(const S &o) {
        std::cout << "non-template copy" << std::endl;
        t = o.t;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>* = nullptr>
    S& operator=(S<U> &&o) {
        std::cout << "template move" << std::endl;

        if(t != o.t) {
            delete t;
            t = std::move(o.t);
            o.t = nullptr;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>* = nullptr>
    S& operator=(const S<U> &o) {
        std::cout << "template copy" << std::endl;
        t = o.t;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    T *t;
};

struct A {};
struct B: A {};

int main() {
    S<B> s1;
    S<B> s2;
    S<A> s3;

    s2 = s1;
    s3 = s2;
    s2 = std::move(s1);
    s3 = std::move(s2);
}
```

That said, the rest of the question is pointless.

Comment: so yup your code shows member function template  move assignment operator is possible, so I was wrong.

Comment: Just curious why did you used swap in one and std::move in other ?

Comment: @pokche In the first case, both the `t` have the same type. In the second case they have different types, but I know that one can be converted to the other one. Because of that, in the first case I can swap them while in the second case it's safer to drop the one to discard and move the other one.

Comment: Can you please add templated assignment operator in the above example as well please so that I could also do s2 = s4 as well, I meant the one with single & because when I try to add I get error saying ambiguous overload for 'operator='

Comment: @pokche Updated answer. Are you going to accept it?

Comment: I found out that the error was due to compiling with g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp .. but when I compile with g++ --std=c++14 main.cpp the error goes away. Do you know why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, to answer this question it is necessary to be precise about template terminology. One thing I've seen that helps is to say the word "template" as late as possible. So we have, relevant to this question, class templates `template <typename T1> class class_template { /* ... */ };`, and member function templates `class non_template { public: template<typename T2> void member_function_template(T2& arg); };`.

Furthermore a class template can have a member function template: `template <typename T3> class also_class_template { public: template<typename T4> void also_member_function_template(T4& arg2); };`

Okay, with that dealt with, we can get to the meat of the question. How and why does a class or class-template provide both MoveConstructable AND template-construction?

```
template<typename T5> class answer_manifest {
public:
  // move constructor
  answer_manifest(answer_manifest&& move_from) { /* ... */ }

  // constructor template that cannot be the move constructor
  template<typename T6> answer_manifest(T6&& template_move_from) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Answer: the class or class-template provides overloaded constructors, one of which is the move-constructor and the other is a constructor template (a member function template for which the member function is a constructor).

Now, this raises the follow-up question, why do we need both? Because the standard says that a member function template for a constructor or assignment operator will never be considered as the move (or copy) constructor or assignment operator. The reason for this is to allow writing of non-copyable classes that have templated constructors (how would you prevent the copy in that case?).

Comment: ok now it  makes sense .. I think I mostly got confused in between assignment operator and member function template assignment operator.